# Wireless adapter not working Realtek

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I bought a Realtek semiconducter Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n wireless LAN Adapter for my Vostro 200 Desktop, as it doesn't come equipped with a PCI card, i went to my grandfathers house as he has the tools and equipment for me to work with, i put Ubuntu 15.04 on it and launched her up, the adapter worked fine, so i brought it home and plugged her in, it didn't work so i retried , rebooted and when i plugged it in it worked. once, it a specific order, i eventually had to shut it down, when i booted it back up, it didn't work i tried this same method and millions of different combinations,none of them successful, if it worked once it should be able to do it again right?, i have no idea, i've messed around in settings and bios and i finally came crawling here, all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver this way. Connect to internet by a cable and run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

Comment: will do but i dont think its a driver problem as it worked 2 other places

Comment: It is a driver problem. Or a wrong encryption in router. First install the driver, if it does not help, check the encryption.

Comment: also, i have a cd with the linux drivers and to get to an ethernet connection would be a real problem and very difficult for me, would it be easier to use a cd?                                      Thank you

Comment: No, It won't be easy to use the CD.

Comment: yah, i tried using the cd but, converting the drivers was not going to be a snappy process, and using ndsiwrapper was not exactly my favourite choice as it being so out of date, but when 15.04 came out and i installed it installed the drivers automatically