# Use laptop wifi on desktop

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, desktop-environments, ip

I have had some  wireless USB problems and I have decided to just try and use the piggyback-a-laptop method.I have an Ethernet cord, a Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop and a Peppermint 5 laptop.I have tried the usual methods, I have not done any IP address and I am kinda frustrated, I've heard stuff about gateway problems, I might go crawling back to windows after 6 years of Linux

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to fix USB wireless problem. It is much easier than to setup network this way.

Comment: well, if you have any advice it is GREATLY appreciated as i have tried all month to fix it, i dont think it is drivers, you can see the post i had about that, sorry about quality

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/655520/wireless-adapter-not-working-realtek

Comment: @Pilot6 actually piggybacking the wifi from a laptop to a desktop is  waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay easy to set up

Comment: @mchid Well. Easy for you and me ;-)

Comment: yah, if its so easy then how do you do it, ive been running ubuntu for ten years of my life, and 5 years on my own pc, i think i could handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of these instructions are for the laptop.

First of all, disable UFW firewall for now:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

- Next, plug the ethernet cable into both computers.
- Now, click on network-manager icon on the laptop and select **edit connections**.
- Click to select the wired connection and then click **edit**.
- Click on the **ipv6 settings** tab and change the **method** to **ignored**.
- Click on the **ipv4 settings** and change the **method** to **shared to other computers** and then click **save**.
- Finally, click **close** on the network-connections tab and run the following command:

  `sudo service network-manager restart`

You may need to run the last command on the desktop as well.

---

If you have dns problems, you may need to install `dnsutils` on the laptop or try using a public server on the desktop.

Comment: Thank YOU!!!! it worked, i have wireless desktop up and running!!

Comment: i think it was the sudo ufw disable, as i followed all other steps previously

Comment: @Soren yeah, I believe you can fix that by allowing incoming access on port 53 to allow DNS requests and posibly 80 and 443 if that's not sufficient but I believe it is although haven't tested it in a while.

Comment: @Soren also, you can accept this answer as the solution by clicking on the icon to the  left to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have a wireless network with resources you need to access from your desktop.

See this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

The easiest would be to make a bridge(laptop):

```
apt-get install bridge-utils
brctl addbr br1
brctl addif br1 eth0
brctl addif br1 wlan0
ifconfig br1 up
dhclient -4 br1
```